# MFMailComposeViewController view or any subviews has been tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently, Im presenting the MFMailComposerViewController in my iOS Application. I wish to know when any of the fields or views in the MFMailComposerViewController get interacted with. I have attempted adding UIGestureRecognizer and adding a transparent UIView over the entire controller but its not working.

When I add a gesture recognizer to all the MFMailComposerViewController view subviews, the selector never gets called.

When I add the overlayed view, I override pointInside:withEvent and return NO but the MFMailComposerViewController views dont receive any events.

Does anyone know of a good solution to know if the user has interacted with the MFMailComposerViewController?

Comment: MFMailComposeViewController is a view controller not a view which is presented moodily so don't  treat it like view.

Comment: obviously. In the description i mentioned "When I add a gesture recognizer to all the MFMailComposerViewController view subviews" this implies that im talking about the view's that the MFMailComposerViewController presents.

Comment: And may be you can add gestures on to it, I personally didn't  did this before. Suggestion : If you are adding gestures then make sure it's instance is not destroyed. you should create your object out side of that class where you are using it,create it like in appDelegate or singleton class